# Will an await in an OnAppearing mean the screen I am navigating to will show up immediately?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

If I have this code:

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await DoLengthDatabaseTaskAsync(); // takes 30 seconds
    }
```

Will the fact that it is an Async task mean that the screen appears quickly and does not wait on the database task to complete?

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await CallAndForgetAboutOutputTaskAsync(); // takes 30 seconds
    }
```

How about if I am not concerned "call and forget" about the completion of the CallAndForgetAboutOutputTaskAsync() method.

Is there a way I can run CallAndForgetAboutOutputTaskAsync() in the background so the screen appears as soon as possible

Comment: The same approach can be taken here by creating an event and async event handler so as not to block the UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

`OnAppearing` means that the page has appeared on the screen and it performs immediately after that. So executing something there won't slow down anything.

However you should keep in mind that `OnAppearing` is executing on the UI thread and depending on the structure of your `CallAndForgetAboutOutputTaskAsync()` it may freeze your UI, but simple magic of `Task.Run` resolves the problem.

EDIT: So it should be like:

```
Task CallAndForget()
{
  return Task.Run(async() => await action());
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how Task.Run could be used in this case? Is that different from using await?

Comment: @Alan2, here is the sample above. It may be different as said above depending on what you do in the method.

Comment: ```CallAndForget()``` no longer needs to be ```async``` and can become a ```void``` method. you're not ```awaiting``` the result of the ```Task.Run()```.

Comment: @ottermatic I've wrote it wrong in the hurry, it shouldn't be async method, thanks for that. But it can't be void, that would be a very bad practice.

Comment: if it isn't ```async```, it doesn't need a return type of ```Task```. it's bad practice to have a return type of ```Task``` that does not feature an ```await``` in the method.

Comment: @ottermatic you can await Task. Returning void is something that should be avoided whenever possible (it is meant to be used only in UI delegates). Please read the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: you are correct, but your example is not ```awaiting``` the ```Task``` and you should be. Your current example, I believe, will block the UI Thread since the ```return``` will force it to wait on the results from the ```Task```. You've created a ```Task.Run().Wait()``` situation.

Comment: @ottermatic ok, we are getting closer to agreement which is good. The last piece of the puzzle that you miss is that in OP code there is `await CallAndForgetAboutOutputTaskAsync();`  which awaits for the task.

Comment: *"... the page has appeared on the screen and it performs immediately after that"* - NO, it happens just BEFORE the page appears. (If it happened AFTER, its name would be `OnAppeared`. Unfortunately, there is no simple way to intercept that moment on at least one platform, hence the lack of such a method.)

Comment: Your fix is correct. But not for the reason you state. OP's version would mean the page does not appear immediately - because as OP coded it, OnAppearing doesn't return until after the method runs, and the page will not show until OnAppearing returns. If CallAndForgetAboutOutputTaskAsync is correctly coded, it WON'T BLOCK UI - that's what `async` method + `await` line does. However the page won't show yet.

Answer (score 2):

No.

[`OnAppearing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms) happens

```
"immediately prior to the Page becoming visible."
```

The purpose of `async`/`await` is to allow UI-accessing code to be written in a linear fashion - each line must complete before the next line executes - WITHOUT blocking UI. That is, UI events still occur - between each `await`.

**However, the `async` method (here, OnAppearing), won't return until all of its lines of code have executed.**

That means the page won't display until after all the work is done.

The compiler turns the method into a sequence of tasks with continuations.

---

IMPORTANT CAVEAT:

It is still necessary for each awaited method ("DoLengthDatabaseTaskAsync") to be well-written with `async`/`await` as needed. Each of those methods *is executed on the UI thread*.

**If that method goes a long time without itself having `await`s, it will block UI during that time.**

async/await does this for you:

1. Allows you to write code that is still executing on the UI thread, so you can access UI elements without cross-threading issues.
2. Allows UI events to occur BETWEEN each `await` line.
3. If the `await`ed method is also async/await, allows UI events to occur between each of its internal `await` lines.

That's all async/await does. It doesn't magically eliminate all UI blocking.

And it isn't always a substitute for `Task.Run`. If you need to do a lengthy operation that *doesn't* access UI elements, use `Task.Run`. That runs code on a *background thread*, so you don't have to be concerned with lengthy operations that lack `await`s.

---

[Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60344040/199364) is one approach. Though the explanation given there is partly wrong.

---

However there is a simpler answer, given that you have a "fire and forget" situation, where you don't need an answer back:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Task.Run(CallAndForgetAboutOutputTaskAsync);
}
```

Code inside `Task.Run` is sent to a *background thread*. The Run immediately returns to the calling method.

Note that I've removed `async` from `OnAppearing` declaration. In this simple case, there is no use of `await`, and there is very little time spent on the ui thread, so there is no need for `async` (which generates a bit of extra code/overhead).

Answer (score -1):

Using an `await` frees up the UI Thread by returning execution to the calling method. This in theory will allow the UI to keep functioning while `CallAndForgetAboutOutputTaskAsync()` does its thing. There is no need for `Task.Run()` in this instance.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it is not like that - test it with httpclient...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth. It does work like that.

Comment: test it and then when you see that it doesn't work try to understand what detail  in the document you've got wrong.

Comment: Using `async` + `await` DOES free up the UI thread. But it DOES NOT return execution to the calling method. (It turns the method into a sequence of tasks with continuations. Each step doesn't occur until the previous task finishes.) The beauty of async/await is that you can code methods in a simple linear fashion, where each line must finish before the next line executes, without blocking UI. That is, UI events still occur. The method however does NOT continue immediately.

Comment: Its also important to understand that each `await` line of code *executes on the UI thread*. That means **if you call a method that isn't well-written, that method will still block the UI thread for however long it takes.** Please look for an article that explains async/await vs Task.Run. They serve different purposes.